# How can there be no autocorrelation in non time-trend simple regression linear model?

Tags: regression

if there is a significant missing factor, disturbance will be affected

and it will affect all the observations. Then how can errors for

each observation be not related?

Answer (score 0):

If the missing factor has a constant effect (same for every period) the residuals will have zero auto-correlation. If the missing factor has a constant growth  effect this will be mis-identified as a steady state trend and again there will be zero correlation . If the missing factor has a stochastic effect that is auto-correlated then this will be proxied by an ARIMA structure "incorrectly" using the past ,,,however if the missing factor is not auto-correlated then there will be zero auto-correlation in the residuals  just inflated variance due to the missing factor.